# Grid and image: too many lines?

Tags: r, image, plot, r-grid

I'm using `image` and `grid` together to plot about 1500 lines of data for 14 variables. I want to do a grid that has vertical lines for the 14 variables and a horizontal line for each of the 1500 respondents.

However when I do this I get a gray plot instead of something that is actually usable. Is there a workaround for this, or do I simply have too many lines?

Here is my code:

```
image(1:14, 1:nrow(df), ylab="", xlab="", as.matrix(t(df[,37:50])), 
      col=c("white","darkblue"),xaxt='n')
grid(nx=14, ny=nrow(df), lty=1, lwd=1, col="lightgrey")
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

But I want it to look something like this:

[image]

But with about 1500 thin horizontal lines.

Comment: Is that your actual image size? You have a height of around 420 pixels and you want to plot 1500 rows? Since it's hard to draw a line smaller than a pixel, i'm sure the `grid()` is just covering everything up. You might want to re-think your visualization.

Comment: This is just a saved PNG version of the graph, when I render it in RStudio I still cannot see it.

Comment: It would still have to be huge in Rstudio to see anything. How many pixels tall is your window?

Comment: No idea, tbh I don;t know how to check.